# Scaling happening from the top left corner when i use the transform property

Tags: html, css

In the following code the item3 is scaling from the top left corner if i use the following line  `transform: translate(-50%,-50%);` but when i remove it then it is scaling from the center. Why is that happening ?

Here is the complete code :-

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(156, 210, 69);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

#item1 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px;
}

#item2 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px;
}

#item3 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px;
}

#item3:hover {
  transform: scale(2, 2);
  transition: transform 2s ease;
}
```

```html
<div id="item1"></div>
<div id="item2"></div>
<div id="item3"></div>
```

Comment: The `hover` `transform` is overwriting the initial state.

Comment: The scaling is always from the center of the element (as you haven't changed the transform-origin) but the translate(-50%, -50%) has disappeared so the element always stays with top: 50% and left: 50%.

Answer (score 0):

The `hover` `transform` is overwriting the initial state. Just either restate the initial state in the `hover` rule (E.g. `transform: scale(2, 2), translate(-50%, -50%);`) **or** separate out the transforms into the (now supported) individual properties.

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(156, 210, 69);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

#item1 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  translate: -50% -50%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px;
}

#item2 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  translate: -50% -50%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px;
}

#item3 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  translate: -50% -50%;
  scale: 1 1;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px;
}

#item3:hover {
  scale: 2 2;
  transition: scale 2s ease;
}
```

```html
<div id="item1"></div>
<div id="item2"></div>
<div id="item3"></div>
```